Queue triggered Premium plan Azure function app not scaling
I have a queue triggered Azure function app in Premium plan inside a VNET. Both the function and the Queue are in the same VNET
As per my understanding of Target Based Scaling, If i set the batch size to 1 and i have 5 messages in the queue i should get 5 instances of the Function App irrespective of CPU and memory usage?
Similarly if i set BatchSize to 2, and i have 10 messages in queue my function should scale up 5 instances and process 2 each so all 10 messages get processed.
However the scaling is not happening. Batch size as 1 is resulting in 1 message being processed at a time with no scaling, Batch size 2 is resulting in concurrency 2 ( as expected) with no scaling...Instance size remains 1.
What am i missing? Documentation state Target based scaling is enabled by default...is there any specific setting i should check?
Does being in a VNET have any impact on target based scaling?

In the Azure Functions Premium plan, the default setting for instances is 1.
Refer this MSDOC for information on instances in Azure Functions Premium.
Instances:
Elastic Scale Out:

Azure application Insights Output:
let grainTime = 30sec;

traces
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| summarize ['rate/minute'] = dcount(cloud_RoleInstance) by bin(timestamp, grainTime)



You can set/Upadate the number of instances in an Azure Functions Premium plan using the Azure CLI with the command below:
az functionapp update -g <RESOURCE_GROUP> -n <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> --set siteConfig.minimumElasticInstanceCount=<YOUR_ALWAYS_READY_COUNT>




Now instances are increased to 5:

After that, I have followed this link to get the List Instance Identifiers of App Service using the REST API.
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances?api-version=2023-12-01

Authorization: Bearer<tokem>


Output:

Batchsize:
You can set a batchSize of 2 in host.json as shown below:
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "batchSize": 2
        }
    },


